# Access .NET Membership on Live or Local provider

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-membership, membership-provider

In my web.config file I have two SQL Server connection strings, one for local and one for live:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <remove name="LocalSqlServer" />
    <add name="LocalSqlServer" connectionString="[removed]" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
    <add name="LiveSqlServer" connectionString="[removed]" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

I then have a "utils" singleton class which basically sets the connection string depending if I'm running the site on "localhost" or on my live server:

```
if (Environment.MachineName.ToUpper() == MyOwnConfig.GetAppSettingsValue(ConfigKeys.localhost).ToUpper()) {
    this.ConnectionString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["LocalSqlServer"].ToString();
    //MembershipProvider provider = Membership.Providers["LocalAspNetMemberSqlProvider"];
    //RoleProvider role = Roles.Providers["LocalAspNetMemberSqlProvider"];
}
else {
    this.ConnectionString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["LiveSqlServer"].ToString();
    //MembershipProvider provider = Membership.Providers["LiveAspNetMemberSqlProvider"];
    //RoleProvider role = Roles.Providers["LiveAspNetMemberSqlProvider"];
}
```

My Database class then simply uses the connectionString property of my utils class. All this works fine so when I place the site locally I can then simply upload it to live without making changes to the connection strings etc in the config file and it starts using my live database.

Now I'm currently implementing "membership" into my site and for ajax for use some webmethods I'm storing the providerUserKey in a text field of the current logged in user. my web method then checks that this key is authenticated. e.g.

```
ajaxCreds.ajaxID1 = ((MembershipUser)Membership.GetUser()).ProviderUserKey.ToString();
```

QUESTION:
the question I have is How do I know if this membership is from the LIVE database or my LOCAL database. As you can see from the web config I've added in the membership/provider lines (commented out) but I don't know how to use them with the above membership.getUser() command.

Alternative... Is this a good way to go? or is it simpler to edit the web.config file when I upload to live?

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most people don't do it this way though I applaud you for figuring all this out.  Typically, people use the deployment manager or some other build system to have a different web.config value on the server verses local.

Here is a link on changing in deployment: [How do I use Web.Config transform on my connection strings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8366091/how-do-i-use-web-config-transform-on-my-connection-strings)

Comment: Many thanks for the link I really like the simple idea of using the debug & release config files. wasn't sure how they were used. I've managed to create my own "localhost" build and create a config file for that. Looking at it I simply just need the one name for my connection string and then point my membership/roles to that name, then in the configs define what the connection is for local & live (debug/release). Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to read this article:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/schlepticons/archive/2010/07/22/modifying-asp-net-providers-at-runtime.aspx

It will show you, that also others were trying to do the similar. And this is how to succeed. Solution (if adjusted) could be similar to your needs.

- put all the providers into your web.config
- On App_Start adjust which will be the default (based on the Environment)
- `Membership` API will be available as you need for Provider Key
- No need to search for Provider by Name

*NOTE: you have to tweak the `void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)` implementation but the idea is there*

*NOTE2: What you are trying to do is definitely **not** exception. Configuration based on environment is pretty smart! What must be achieved is standard API usage, e.g. calls via Manager pattern*

- System.Web.Security.Membership
- System.Web.Security.Roles

*and not calls to the providers by name.*

Comment: +up Thanks for the link and information, I'll have a look into this but at first glance Peters answer with configs seems to be the easiest way.