# Azure MobileServices Live/UAT/Dev environments

Tags: mobile, azure

I have an azure mobile service that will go live at some point. So I need to create UAT and dev versions which would point to the UAT and dev databases. What I am struggling with is how to create these.

The namespace in my live, UAT and Dev databases need to be the same but if I create a new mobile service called myAppName_UAT, it's going to want to use MyAppName_UAT as the namespace and so will not find any of the tables.

Has anyone overcome this problem? Once the product goes live I'll need to be able to test the mobile apps against the Dev db without affecting live which surely must be a common scenario?

Any advice would be very gratefully received.

Edit: What I'm specifically after is how to manage the multiple environments within the Azure Portal. I can deploy all the other components of my UAT environment but I'm stuck on the mobile service.

I am not asking for a way for my applications to switch config files or to migrate data between databases. Does anyone have any experience of running azure applications with multiple components where they ran multiple mobile services?

Answer (score 1):

Do you use a Version Control? For me, you just need to create branches to separate the 'UAT' and 'dev' versions.

About the databases:

You can use web.config transformations to switch the connection string between your databases.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465326.aspx

[How do I use Web.Config transform on my connection strings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8366091/how-do-i-use-web-config-transform-on-my-connection-strings)

```
=================================================================================
```

Update:

Ok, now I understood what you want.

Create your two versions of mobile services:

```
1-Log in Windows Azure Management Portal (http://manage.windowsazure.com)
2-Create your test mobile services (if you already have then, skip this step):
  2.1- New -> Compute -> Mobile Services
  2.2- Url - MyMobileServicesTest
  2.3- Database -> Create a new (test db).

3-Create your production mobile services (if you already have then, skip this step):
  2.1- New -> Compute -> Mobile Services
  2.2- Url - MyMobileServicesProduction
  2.3- Database -> Create a new (production db).
```

Right now, you have two different versions.

Using Windows Azure SDK:

```
//public static MobileServiceClient MobileService = new MobileServiceClient( 
//    "AppUrl", 
//    "AppKey" 
//);
```

Pay attention: AppUrl will be "MyMobileServicesTest.azure-mobile.net/" or "MyMobileServicesProduction.azure-mobile.net/". The app key, each environment will have it's own. You can store this settings in a config file and switch according to what you are doing.

More information:

http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/mobile/tutorials/get-started-with-data-dotnet/

Comment: Thanks Thiago, it's more a problem with creating the azure mobile service within the portal itself. So I've got one mobile service which uses the name of my product. I can't create another one with the same name so if I call it something different it is going to expect a different namespace in the DB which is what I don't want.

Comment: Please, let me know if I understood correctly. You want a dev version, and a production version, right? You want to create new features in your dev environment and then deploy to production. Is that what you want?

Comment: That's right so I'd need three azure mobile services. Prod, UAT and dev. But these are setup in the Azure portal and they cannot have the same name. The name you give the mobile service determines what the db schema is called so I'm trying to find a way to have the same schema name in each of my databases and have a corresponding azure mobile service.

Comment: Hi Thiago, that's kind of what I'm after but wouldn't this mean that the mobile services would be looking for their data in MyMobileServicesTest.MyTable and MyMobileServicesProduction.MyTable? I need to keep the database schemas exactly the same so that other parts of the application can share the data.

Comment: Ok, now I got it. What you want, is a way to sync your databases. You create a new feature in dev, deploy it to UAT and if it is ok, deploy to production. There a few ways to do that. Take a look at SSDT. http://msdn.microsoft.com/data/tools   http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ssdt   http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/hh297027

Comment: Not quite. The MyMobileServicesProduction mobile service will create data in MyMobileServicesProduction.Customer table in the Prod DB. Similarly the MyMobileServicesTest mobile service will create data in MyMobileServicesTest.Customer table in the UAT database. These are not the same schemas and I need them to be. Otherwise other parts of the application, say a website, would need to change the schema on all the tables in code first EF just to change environments. I don't want to change the website at all. I just want a copy of my mobile service that points to the same tables names in UAT

Comment: If you want the same schema, during the creating of WAMS (windows azure mobile services), instead of create a new database, just point to a database that you already have. It's not the recommendation, since you'll see production data in your dev environment (for example). The best way, is to work as I told you, separate the environments / database and then, use SSDT to migrate de schema and also data among environments.

Comment: As it stands I have one mobile service pointing to the prod DB. If I create a new mobile service and point it to the uat database it won't be able to see the data. It can only see data in a schema called the same as the mobile service. This is the problem. I can migrate data up and down and point the rest of my applications at the right mobile service, the problem is that any mobile service that I create won't be able to see the data.

Answer (score 0):

Multiple mobile services can share the same database. You only need to specify the same schema name in web.config in each mobile service:

```
<appSettings>    
  <add key="MS_MobileServiceName" value="MyAppName" />
</appSettings>
```

**Updated:**

The setting above only works in localhost, but not after publishing to live.
Need to do the following trick in order to make it work. Just hard code the schema name into function `OnModelCreating`. This way the database schema name will not depend on the mobile service name any more:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
   string schema = "MyAppName"; // ServiceSettingsDictionary.GetSchemaName();
   if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(schema))
   {
       modelBuilder.HasDefaultSchema(schema);
   }

   modelBuilder.Conventions.Add(
          new AttributeToColumnAnnotationConvention<TableColumnAttribute, string>(
         "ServiceTableColumn", (property, attributes) => attributes.Single().ColumnType.ToString()));
}
```