# App.Config transformation not working

Tags: c#, xml, tfs, tfsbuild

I am trying to change the app.config dinamically on my build server, I created a Configuration called Build, and I have these 4 .config files.

this is my app.config

```
<connectionStrings>
    <!--configSource="connectionStrings.config"-->
    <add name="TestContext" connectionString="Data Source=ServerDoesNotExist;Initial Catalog=TestDb; Integrated Security=true" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

and on my app.build.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform">
  <connectionstrings xdt:transform="Replace">
      <add name="TestContext" connectionstring="Data Source=REALEXISTINGSERVER;Initial Catalog=TestDb; Integrated Security=true" providername="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
  </connectionstrings>
</configuration>
```

However when I created the build definition and added the `configuration =Build` I get this error

> Error: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server) ---> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: The network path was not found

Which means is taking the app.config file and not the transformation

Comment: Have you checked that the file is getting correctly transformed on your local macine (ie from Visual Studio). It could be wrong build action on the transform file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use SetAttributes

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="TestContext" connectionString="Data Source=REALEXISTINGSERVER;Initial Catalog=TestDb; Integrated Security=true" providername="System.Data.SqlClient" 
    xdt:Transform="SetAttributes" xdt:Locator="Match(name)"/>
  </connectionStrings>
```

please refer to

[How do I use Web.Config transform on my connection strings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8366091/how-do-i-use-web-config-transform-on-my-connection-strings)